# PHP batch convert all images in a folder to jpg using Image Magick

Tags: php

I have uploaded a number of images with different formats to a folder on my server. Using ImageMagick I want to convert them and replace them to JPG.

This is my code:

```
<?php

try
{
        /*** the image file ***/
        $image = 'temp_images/*.*';

        /*** a new imagick object ***/
        $im = new Imagick();

        /*** ping the image ***/
        $im->pingImage($image);

        /*** read the image into the object ***/
        $im->readImage( $image );

        /**** convert to png ***/
        $im->setImageFormat( "jpg" );

        /*** write image to disk ***/
        $im->writeImage( 'temp_images/input/*.jpg' );

        echo 'Image Converted';
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
        echo $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

When I specify a particular image it converts it, when I replace say `abc.gif` to `*.*` I get the following error.

> 'unable to open image `temp_images/input/*.*`: No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2638'

In the documentation I read that I can use mogrify but I do not know who to insert comand line into PHP.

Comment: You need to get each file in the folder first; you will not be done that automatically.

Comment: The files are already in the folder.

Comment: Yes, but you need to fetch a list of them and `foreach` it. http://php.net/glob will help.

Answer (score 1):

You can't specify a filename with wildcards like that.

You can use http://php.net/glob or the [directory functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.dir.php) to fetch a list of files matching your requirements, and then step through them using a `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need PHP for that, you can do it in the shell directly:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob nocaseglob # Ignore case and errors
for i in *.png *.tif *.bmp   # Do all images except JPEGs
do
   newname=${i%.*}.jpg       # Strip file extension
   convert "$i" "$newname"   # Convert to JPEG
done
```

Or, if you really want to do it within PHP, you can use `system()` to execute the script above.